# How should I understand this twin coil relay pinout? (Screenshot)

Tags: relay, automotive, test, testing

I'm currently looking on an automotive twin coil relay. The Datasheet gives me following schematic:

[image: Twin coil Relay pinout]

My Question is: How could I test this relay? In other cases I put the corresponding Voltage on the coil pins and I could hear the changing sound, but where is the coil in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This relay has two coils:

- First coil is between pins 1 and 2. It triggers the double throw switch with the common 6, NO 8 and NC 5.
- The second coil is between pins 3 and 4. It triggers the double throw switch with the common 7, NO 8 and NC 5.

It appears that pin 8 and 5 should connect to the battery (+) and (-). Power coil 1-2 and the motor gets (+) on 6 and (-) on 7. Power coil 3-4 and the motor gets (-) on 6 and (+) on 7.

If both coils are powered, the motor is off and shortcircuited (it gets connected with its both poles to the (+)).

Comment: Yes, you could consider this two interconnected SPDT relays in one package.

Answer (score 0):

This twin coil relay enables you to drive a high power motor in both directions and brake it by short circuiting it to + or - depending on low power signals on the coils. The contact positions shown are for unenergised states:

If 1-2 and 3-4 are energised, the motor brakes from +.
If 1-2 is energised and 3-4 is not, the motor runs in one direction
If 1-2 is not energised and 3-4 is, the motor runs in the other direction
If 1-2 and 3-4 are not energised, the motor brakes from -.

Plug your power supply in 8 and 5, the motor in 6 and 7, and drive the coils 1-2 and 3-4 with a combination of high and low voltages.